# Flash question about expanding the derivative definition

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I'm trying to do a physics estimation and I need your help with an assumption that I'm making:

My flash question is: Is it true that

> $$(f(x) \cdot x^2)'=\lim_{h \to 0}\ \frac{f(x+h)(x+h)^2-f(x)\cdot
>  x^2}{h} ?$$

I'm trying to expand the definition of the derivate in a point for $f(x):$. 
$$ f(x)'=\lim_{h \to 0}\ \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} $$

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Looks good to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is ok. In general, given

$$h:=f\cdot g,$$

with $h(x)=f(x)g(x)$, then

$$h^{'}(x):=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x+h)g(x+h)-f(x)g(x)}{h}.$$

In your case $g(x):=x^2$.